# jQuery - prop "Disabled" not working in version of IE

Tags: jquery

so I have this

```
<input type="text" id="value" name="value" placeholder="please enter a value" class="searchtext" title="value"> 

$("#value").prop('disabled', true);
```

Hi so this particualy piece of jquery works fine for All versions of IE, Chrome , Firefox,

but when I test on a machine that has IE version: 10,.0.9200.17414CO

Im able to modify this field.....any idea?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Does it work to diable the field if you use vanilla JS?

Answer (score 0):

The 'disabled' property is actually an attribute, therefore you will need to use the jQuery '.attr()' function.

```
$("#value").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```